# How do VPN Servers handle packets that are received from the VPN Client?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

To start off, my knowledge in networking is quite limited so I apologize in advance if I am using the wrong terminology.

### Situation

I'm trying to create a prototype that will allow clients to communicate with a local web server on a different network. The webserver is hosted on the same network as the VPN server.
So far, I'm able to route the client packet (ex: SYN) to a virtual interface (tun) and send the entire packet to the VPN Server. On the Server side, I receive these packets, change the source and destination IPs, and recalculate the checksums inside the headers.

To reiterate, the flow is as follows:

1. User tries to access web server with a certain ip address.
2. The SYN packet is sent to the virtual interface because it matches routes in the routing table.
3. The VPN Client application sends the SYN packet to the VPN Server through an established websocket connection (shouldn't matter what kind of connection this is)
4. The VPN Server receives the packet and modifies the source / destination ip address to point to the actual web server hosted on the same network.
5. How do I send these packets to the webserver and receive responses from the webserver? I want the client to communicate with the webserver through the VPN server / established web socket connection. What are some options I have?

#### Question

How can I send these packets to the web server, and receives packets back from the webserver to send back to the client? Do I "inject" packets into the correct interface and make sure my application sends the responses back to the client? I want the client to communicate with the webserver through the VPN server / established web socket connection. What are some options I have and in general, how do current VPN Server's do this?

#### What I have tried

What I've tried to do on the server side is I've created a virtual interface (tun) and wrote the packets received from the client into the interface. However, these packets do not get sent out to the webserver. The client and server are running on macOS using Network Extensions if that is of any use. The web server is running on `192.168.1.95`, and I've modified the packet's source IP to `100.64.0.77` before writing to the `tun` interface.

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGSc           en0       
default            link#10            UCSI         utun2       
100.64.0.77        100.64.0.77        UH           utun2       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#10            UCSI         utun2       
192.168.1.92/32    link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.99       8c:a9:82:2e:d6:2e  UHLWI          en0    986
192.168.1.254/32   link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.254      70:f1:96:86:e6:a0  UHLWIir        en0   1196
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#10            UmCSI        utun2       
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCS            en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#10            UCSI         utun2
```

`

Answer (score 0):

> The VPN Server receives the packet and modifies the source / destination ip address to point to the actual web server hosted on the same network.

This shouldn't ever be needed, because the client has already specified the destination IP address they want. (VPNs *encapsulate* the original packet inside another IP packet, without altering the original IP header, so the server only needs to decapsulate it again and forward the original packet exactly as it was.)

NAT can be done (and is occassionally done), but it's more often the OS firewall's job and the sysadmin's decision – it shouldn't be done by the VPN software all on its own. And in general, communications within an internal network should not *need* NAT; using it is often an indication that your network's elementary routing is not set up right.

> How do I send these packets to the webserver and receive responses from the webserver? I want the client to communicate with the webserver through the VPN server / established web socket connection. What are some options I have?

Typically, the VPN server will have a virtual interface exactly like the VPN client and will use exactly the same mechanisms to produce and receive packets. (Some will create dedicated virtual interfaces per client, others will have a single interface for all clients.) If your client is using a `tun` interface, your server can do the same.

Comment: On the server side I have created a `tun` interface. Afterwards, I write the packets received from the client to this interface. But, I can see that I am not receiving any packets on the web server side. I've edited my question to contain my routing table. Any more help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the server's operating system receive the packets via tun0 (i.e. `tcpdump -ni tun0`)? Does the server's operating system have IP forwarding enabled? Does the server's operating system send the packets out through eth0/en0?

Comment: Yes, packets are being received. Using `tcpdump -ni utun2` I can see the packets I am writing into the interface. Before this comment, I did not have IP forwarding enabled. I have now enabled it with command `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` on the Mac machine running the VPN server. Now, I can see the SYN/ACK being sent from the web server to `en0` interface on the VPN server's side. But now, how can I get this SYN/ACK to go to the `tun` interface so that my application can read the response from it? Your comments have been a great help so far!

Comment: Does the utun2 interface actually have an IP address from the correct subnet configured? (This now sounds like a general networking problem that would apply equally to ethernet, nothing tun-specific.)

Comment: How can I check this/set an IP address to the interface? Using `ifconfig` I can see that the `utun2` interface contains information `inet 10064.0.77 --> 100.64.0.77 netmask 0xffffff00`. The SYN/ACK packet has IP source of `192.168.1.95` and destination of `100.64.0.77`.